# Computing the MultinormalDistribution density gives sometimes different values from in-built function

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, numerical-value

I'm trying to define the density of the Multivariate Normal distribution, since it will be faster to compute for greater dimensions (vectors of size 50 or more), specially when I have to do those computations many times (10,000).

I've defined the density as :

```
multinormalDens[x_, mean_, var_] := Module[{},
   Det[2*Pi*var]^(-0.5)*Exp[-0.5*(x - mean).Inverse[var].(x - mean)]
   ];
```

I use the Wishart to provide with several positive definite covariance matrices.

```
varmat = RandomVariate[
   WishartMatrixDistribution[52, IdentityMatrix[50]], 10000];
meanmat = Table[RandomReal[{0, 5}, 50], {i, 1, 10000}];
```

They will all be evaluated for the same point:

```
x0 = RandomReal[{0, 5}, 50];
```

Now running the comparison for 10,000 tries, I get:

```
In[43]:= Table[
  multinormalDens[x0, meanmat[[i]], varmat[[i]]] == 
   PDF[MultinormalDistribution[meanmat[[i]], varmat[[i]]], x0], {i, 1,
    Length[varmat]}] // Total

Out[43]= 6643 False + 3357 True
```

How come I have 6643 different outcomes? Are they from the matrix inversion?

Edit:

```
data = Table[
   multinormalDens[x0, meanmat[[i]], varmat[[i]]] - 
    PDF[MultinormalDistribution[meanmat[[i]], varmat[[i]]], x0], {i, 
    1, Length[varmat]}];



ListPlot[data]
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe it is interesting to look at the distribution of the differences.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I've plotted a graphic. ;)

Comment: These (absolute) errors are really tiny. (The relative errors might be much larger...) In terms of probability, they may certainly be neglected.

Comment: There are two major source for numerical errors: The matrix inversion is one. But more important are probably the underflows caused by `Exp[-(...)]` with large arguments.

Comment: Your definition of `meanmat` can be simplified to `meanmat = RandomReal[{0, 5}, {10000, 50}];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is less about accuracy (it is already good) but about getting rid of the `General::munfl` messages. Before the final number is computed, we should check whether the logarithm of the result is below (a multiple of) `Log[$MinMachineNumber]`; if yes, we simply set the result to `0`.

```
multinormalDens[x_, mean_, var_] := Module[{t, det},
   t = 0.5*(x - mean).LinearSolve[var, (x - mean)];
   det = Det[2*Pi*var]^(0.5);
   If[-t - Log[det] < 10. Log[$MinMachineNumber], 0., Exp[-t]/det]
   ];
```

Comment: Henrik, thanks for the answer. What are the General::munfl messages ? They don't show up in my notebook...

Comment: Yes, it's likely that they do not appear if you use version 11.2 or older. Wolfram Research added these messages due to introduction of a different underflow handling in version 11.3. The aim is to be closer to the IEEE 754 standard for floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks Henrik ;)

Comment: Always at your service! =)